# Swift binary operator in while statement

Tags: swift

New to Swift, small hurdle. This code

```
let viewH = self.view.frame.size.width
let boxH = viewH/60
var curY = 0

while curY<=viewH-boxH {
    //do something
}
```

Throws the error "Binary operator <= cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'CGFloat'. Do I need to explicitly cast my variables and constants? To what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small hurdle, small fix. Your problem is that `curY` is an `Int` and the subtraction result on the right is a `CGFloat` (what `width` is returning you). So all you need to do is convert `curY` to a `CGFloat` as well:

```
var curY = 0 as CGFloat
```

or alternatively:

```
var curY: CGFloat = 0
```

Comment: Small indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @Firo when I use your solution this times I get this warring says "Cast from Int unrelated type CGFloat always fails", any idea?

Comment: Which solution and which version of Swift? (You can try `var curY = CGFloat(0)`)